# How to Create List within SharePoint 2013 Apps?

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I am developing `Apps` for `SharePoint 2013`. And I want to create Multiple list in My App Package *programmatically*.
It is like user inputs Name of list and when he clicks the Create Button the list with the same name should be created in my App not in SharePoint site.

I have created the `AutoHosted App` using Client Side Object Model technology.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Are there problems with using like this code: http://thesharepointhelper.blogspot.se/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-create-list-using.html ?

Comment: Yes sir I have created list like that. But I want list in My App. Not in SharePoint site...

Comment: By passing in the url to the app web it will be created in the App..

Comment: Sir can you tell me how to pass the AppWebUrl to create List. And where to pass.

Comment: var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;pass in webUrl to the function creating the list

Comment: What kind of app are you developing and which API are you using? (SharePoint-hosted REST/JSOM, Autohosted REST/CSOM, Provider-hosted REST/CSOM)

Comment: I am developing Autohosted App using CSOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
When I was creating the ContextToken object in that I was passing the SPHostUrl of the request but instead of that I passed SPAppWebUrl So using that it get the token of the AppWebUrl and thus it created the list in my App not in SharePoint site.

Like bellow code:

```
var hostWeb = Page.Request["SPAppWebUrl"]; //This will get the URL of AppWeb not SharePoint site...

using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithContextToken(hostWeb, ContextToken, Request.Url.Authority))
{
     //Code for creating list or manipulating them...
     //This ClientContext is created for the AppWeb.
}
```

When I was searching the code for creating every time I was finding the hostWeb object is created using SPHostUrl Therefore I asked this question.
**Thank you everyone for your help.**